# Property 'user' does not exist on type '{ body: { name: any; description: any; date: string | number | Date; }; }'

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a problem with my angular app, I am trying to connect my angular app to my DB, but I have this error

> (Property 'user' does not exist on type '{ body: { name: any; description: any; date: string | number | Date; }; }'

can someone help me?

HERE IS MY CODE>

```
    router.post('/event', (req: { body: { name: any; description: any; date: string | number | Date; }; }, res: { status: (arg0: number) => { (): any; new(): any; json: { (arg0: { status: string; }): void; new(): any; }; }; }, next: any) => {
    const owner = req.user.email;
    db.query(
      'INSERT INTO events (owner, name, description, date) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',
      [owner, req.body.name, req.body.description, new Date(req.body.date)],
      (error: any) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error(error);
          res.status(500).json({status: 'error'});
        } else {
          res.status(200).json({status: 'ok'});
        }
      }
    );
  });
```

Comment: Because the `req` parameter has a type that does not include the property `user`

Comment: so what would be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. use interface for more clarity.

`interface Request { body: Body; user: any; }`

```
interface Body {
    name: any;
    description: any;
    date: string | number | Date;
}
```

2. Replace :

`router.post('/event', (req: { body: { name: any; description: any; date: string | number | Date; }; },`

with :

```
router.post('/event', (req: Request, ...
```